# python class which connects, find and update mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to make python class which connects, update and find my mongodb database.  I am able to connect, but it gives me error when trying to find data using this class. I will appreciate if some one can help me debug this issue.

here is my class definition:

```
import string
import pymongo

class mongoresultDAO(object):

       def __init__(self, database, collection):
               self.db = database
               self.dbcollection = collection
               self.connect()

       def find_names(self, model, query, param):
               #print query
               #print param
               mongor1 = self.dbcollection.find(query, param)
               #print mongor1
               return mongor1

       def update_collection(self,jsonObj):
               self.dbcollection.insert(jsonObj,check_keys=False)

      def connect(self):
               client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
               db = client[self.db]
               coll_obj = db[self.dbcollection]
               return coll_obj
```

I get following error when trying to find information:

```
a=sresult1.find_names("test", query, param) File 
"/Documents/lab_python/mongoresultDAO.py", line 14, in find_names mongor1 = 
self.dbcollection.find(query, param) TypeError: slice indices must be 
integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a `main`. Because right now, the code runs without error.

Comment: I guess the problem arises from the fact, that `self.dbcollection` is a string (suggested by use in your `__init__` and `connect` methods), while in `update_collection` method you treat it as a collection object. Thus, you are actually not using collection object's `find` method, but string `find` method.